# Как вращать слайдер только на определенный блок заданной для него стрелкой?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slick.js

Есть слайдер, который хочу управлять таким образом, чтобы каждая заданная стрелка `#slider-scheme-arrow` открывала свой блок с картинкой, 
т.е. `<div id="slider-scheme-arrow-1">first</div>` соотв `<div class="first_sheme_description">..</div>`

Сейчас слайдер вращается произвольно - [фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/sta2vbcm/2/)

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  infinite: true,
  cssEase: 'linear'
});

$('#slider-scheme-arrow-1').on('click', function() {
  //while (!$('.slider .slick-current').hasClass("first_sheme_description")) {
  $('.slider').slick('slickNext');
  //}
});

$('#slider-scheme-arrow-2').on('click', function() {
  //while (!$('.slider .slick-current').hasClass("second_sheme_description")) {
  //if ($('.slider .slick-current').hasClass("first_sheme_description")) {
  $('.slider').slick('slickNext');
  //} else {
  //  $('.slider').slick('slickPrev');
  //}
  //}
});

$('#slider-scheme-arrow-3').on('click', function() {
  //while (!$('.slider .slick-current').hasClass("third_sheme_description")) {
  $('.slider').slick('slickPrev');
  //}
});
```

```css
img {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#slider-scheme-arrow-1,
#slider-scheme-arrow-2,
#slider-scheme-arrow-3 {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>
  <div id="slider-scheme-arrow-1">first</div>
  <div id="slider-scheme-arrow-2">second</div>
  <div id="slider-scheme-arrow-3">third</div>
</div>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="first_sheme_description">
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="second_sheme_description">
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz2.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="third_sheme_description">
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz3.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: надо проста поставить точки и для каждой задать имя ничего сложного.

Comment: @Избыток сусликов поставить точки понятно, а как каждой задать имя с `id` ?

Comment: таким образом имя получается единое для всех
    `.slick-dots li button:first-of-type:before {
      font-size: 20px;
      content: "first";
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот точно как ты хотел.

Называй имя  дата атрибутов как хочешь и пользуйся на здоровье

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  dots:true,
  prevArrow: '<a class="slick-prev" href="#"><i data-icon="ei-arrow-left" data-size="m"></i></a>',
  nextArrow: '<a class="slick-next" href="#"><i data-icon="ei-arrow-right" data-size="m"></i></a>',
  customPaging: (slick,index)  => {
     let targetName = slick.$slides.eq(index).find('li').data('name');
        return `<p> ${targetName} </p>`;
     }
});
```

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.layout {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  position: relative;
}
.layout a {
  color: #666;
}

.slide {
  display: none;
}
.slide li {
  list-style: none;
}
.slide.slick-initialized {
  display: block;
}

.slick-dots {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-right: -5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.slick-dots li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 112px;
  max-hegiht: 56px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.slick-dots li img {
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.slick-dots li.slick-active img {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slick-prev {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  top: 120px;
  left: -50px;
}

.slick-next {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  top: 120px;
  right: -50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/evil-icons/1.9.0/evil-icons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kenwheeler/slick/master/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/evil-icons/1.9.0/evil-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/kenwheeler/slick/master/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="layout">
  <ul class="slider">
    <li data-name="blue"> 
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/600/300/?image=42">
    </li>
    <li data-name="red"> 
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/600/300/?image=43">
    </li>
    <li data-name="gray"> 
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/600/300/?image=49">
    </li>
    <li data-name="lion"> 
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/600/300/?image=60">
    </li>
    <li data-name="ronni"> 
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/600/300/?image=106">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще альтернативный ответ, который гораздо проще будет - это воспользоваться методом `slickGoTo` с указанием индекса слайда.

```
$('.slider').slick('slickGoTo', 0, true);
```